# New Layout: Editor _before_ author?

Tags: feature-request, theme-2018

I was just confused by something in the layout:

Look at *any* question or answer that has been edited. picture has just one example). The person who most recently edited the question is first, the originator of the question comes second. Also, that second listing is darkened. These too items make the name of the originating author much less noticeable and the latest author very noticeable.

[image]

This seems very counter-intuitive to me. The primary author of a piece is the one who first submitted it. Edits are expected to be minor and fix typos, add secondary matter, extend content, or otherwise *not* change the general intent. The original author is the one who set the tone for everything.

I'm sure there is a justification for the difference, like 'It was easier to implement with the new changes', or 'Oh, I don't think it matters'. To be clear, it is *very* counter-intuitive.

- Is this a feature change in the new layout (i.e. did the new layout change things from the one it replaced)?
- Is the justification for the change stronger than ... *clears throat* ... common sense?

Which is all to say...can we change this egregious solecism back?

Comment: I don't see it like that. I see the editor at the centre and the OP on the right side. Maybe you have a bug?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ahhh. I see. It is a matter of zoom level, which explains the implementation which causes this. If I zoom out just once, I get what I think you see, the most recent edit followed by the original submission, flush left. Zooming in, the layout renderer pushes the 2nd element (the original) down. So nothing is done on purpose, it's just a natural result of the browser rendering. But it is still a problem.

Comment: It's not zoom per se. If you make your browser window smaller, you will also see this.

Comment: And the name/identity block of *the author of the question (i.e., the OP)* is shaded wherever it appears on the page (e.g., as the author of an answer, or the editor of an answer that they didn't write, or the author of a comment). That's been like that for years.